# Let $ \alpha=2^{1/5} $ and $\zeta=e^{2i\pi/5} $ and let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\zeta) $ then how many field automorphism of $K $ have?

Tags: field-theory

Let $\alpha=2^{1/5} $ and $\zeta =e^{2i\pi/5} $ .Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\zeta) $. My first question does $K $ look like as below:

$K$ ={ $ b_0+b_1(\alpha\zeta)+b_2 (\alpha\zeta)^2+b_3 (\alpha\zeta)^3+b_4 (\alpha\zeta)^4 : b_i \in \mathbb{Q} $}

how many field automorphism of $K $ have ?

I think only one because  any automorphism $g $ of $K $ will take $ \alpha\zeta $ to a root of the polynomial $x^5-2$ contained in $K $ but  $K $ contains only one root of  $x^5-2$ which is $ \alpha\zeta $ .

Am I right ?  Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This question is different because  I asked here how many automorphism of $K $ have? I am sure that I didn't ask this question anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can **prove** that $\alpha\zeta$ is the only fifth root of $2$ in $K$, can't you?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. The splitting field of $x^5-2$ would have a total of $20$ automorphisms.

Comment: @lord sir I showed that $2^{1/5}$ can't be in $K$ because then  $e^{2i\pi/5}$ will also be in $K $ but then $K $ will be the splitting field of $x^5-2$ which is not possible since $[K:\mathbb {Q}] = 5 $ and similarly for the same reason $e^{2i\pi/5} $ can't be in $K $ so $K $ only contains the root  $\alpha\zeta $.Is it the right way?

Comment: Thank you so much jyrki lantonen sir ..will you please give me a little hint about  the existence of a field automorphism of  $\mathbb{C} $ ,  different from identity which takes  $K $ onto itself .

Comment: Also related; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183084/let-alpha-21-5-zeta-e2i-pi-5-and-k-mathbbq-alpha-zeta-can-t

Answer (score 0):

$K|_{\mathbb Q}$ is a degree $5$ extension with normal closure $\mathbb Q(2^{\frac{1}{5}}\zeta_5, 2^{\frac{1}{5}})$ which has degree $20$

First of all any automorphism fixes $\mathbb Q$  as it's a prime field. So $\alpha \zeta_5$ must go to another $5$th root of $2$. If any other $5$ th root of $2$ is there then $\mathbb Q(\alpha\zeta_5): \mathbb Q \geq 20$ , a contradiction.

So any automorphism fixes $\alpha \zeta_5$ as well and hence identify is the only such automorphism.