# Let $\alpha=2^{1/5}$ ,$\zeta=e^{2i\pi/5}$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\zeta)$, can the field automorphism of K be extended to an automorphism of C?

Tags: field-theory, galois-extensions

Let $\alpha=2^{1/5} $ and $\zeta=e^{2i\pi/5}$.Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\zeta) $ . I just read a theorem which is $-$ Any automorphism of a subfield of $\mathbb{C} $ can be extended  to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$.

Per [my previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182543/let-alpha-21-5-and-zeta-e2i-pi-5-and-let-k-mathbbq-alpha-zet) the only automorphism of $K$ is identity automorphism, and by the above theorem it can be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb {C} $ .

My question is $-$  Is the extended automorphism identity or nonidentity automorphism of $\mathbb{C} $.

Edit: Here the question is whether the extended automorphism is identity or non-identity automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$.  I am sure I didn't ask THIS question anywhere else.

Comment: It can be anything.

Comment: Also related; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182543/let-alpha-21-5-and-zeta-e2i-pi-5-and-let-k-mathbbq-alpha-zet

Comment: thank you @soumik ghosh sir,    can you tell me the reason please ?  If I consider the $\mathbb{R}$ then we all know there exists an automorphism complex conjugation of $\mathbb{C}$  which takes $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself but in this case it is really difficult for me to construct a nonidentity automorphism on $\mathbb {C}$  which takes  $K $ onto itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L={\bf Q}(\alpha,\zeta)$, so $L$ is a Galois extension of $\bf Q$ containing $K$. There are twenty automorphisms of $L$ fixing $\bf Q$. Many of them also fix $K$. Take one of those, not the identity, and extend it to an automorphism of $\bf C$, and you're done.

Comment: But, suchanda, you really should link each of your several questions about this field $K$ to each of the others.

Comment: Thank you for answering Gerry sir,  though I didn't understand the line " many of them also fix  $K $", I mean automorphisms fix $\mathbb{Q} $ ,we all know that but how did  you say so easily that many of them fix $K $,I didn't understand that

Comment: But it is easy to think when someone knows the extension of automorphism, again  I didn't understand that too,I am working on understanding that extension of automorphism thing but thanks anyway

Comment: I'm saying there are automorphisms of $L$ (other than the identity) that fix $K$, for example, there is an automorphism that takes $\alpha$ to $\alpha\zeta^{-1}$ and takes $\zeta$ to $\zeta^2$. Then that automorphism fixes $\alpha\zeta$, so it fixes $K$. Then you stated a theorem which guarantees that that automorphism can be extended to an automorphism of $\bf C$ which isn't the identity (since it moves both $\alpha$ and $\zeta$) but fixes $K$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir  , it's difficult for me to construct  an automorphism...like you did. .with regards